# Generate random/dummy dataset on the basis of column name and datatype in excel using Python

Tags: python, sql, shell, automation, teradata

Can anyone please suggest a way to automate on how to create a table in teradata and load random records on the basis of schema?

And intended output should be random 50-100 records on the basis of schema, like if datatype is varchar then output can be any random string(like in this case, crime, doctor, sdfsdc, asdfadf) and similarly with int and any other datatype.

I have tried a piece of code which generates the data according to the data_type, but i am stuck with header part. How to create a header of the output file on the basis of column_name?

Code which i tried

````
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import openpyxl

import random

wb=openpyxl.Workbook()

ws=wb.active

fake_data=Faker()

df=openpyxl.load_workbook('inputcsv.xlsx')

df_sheet=df['inputcsv']

ColNames = {}

Current = 0

for COL in df_sheet.iter_cols(1, df_sheet.max_column):

  ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current

  Current += 1

counter=0

for row_cells in df_sheet.iter_rows():

  if row_cells[ColNames['type']].value == 'int':

    for i in range(2,201):

      ws.cell(row=i,column=counter).value = random.randint(-10000,10000)

  if row_cells[ColNames['type']].value == 'char':

    for i in range(2,201):

      ws.cell(row=i,column=counter).value = chr(random.randint(65,90))

  if row_cells[ColNames['type']].value == 'string':

    for i in range(2,201):

      ws.cell(row=i,column=counter).value = fake_data.name()

  counter+=1

wb.save('testdata.xlsx') ```


My input file looks like:


| col_name| type   |
|:--------|:------:|
| name    | string |
| address | string | 
| city    | char   |
| phonenum| int    |


My output looks like:

| saurabh | adgsdf | C | 4534  |
| eeshan  | sgsdfsd| A | 356356| 
| ravinder| adgadf | G | 45343 |



Can someone please help on getting headers of output file from the input file column col_name?

output should look like this:

| name    | address | city| phonenum|
|---------|---------|-----|---------|
| saurabh | adgsdf  | C   | 4534    |
| eeshan  | sgsdfsd | A   | 356356  | 
| ravinder| adgadf  | G   | 45343   |
````

Comment: "I need a solution with these specs". It sounds like you need a developer. This is much too broad for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import random

wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
ws=wb.active
fake_data=Faker()
df=openpyxl.load_workbook('inputcsv.xlsx')
df_sheet=df['inputcsv']

ColNames = {}
Current = 0

for COL in df_sheet.iter_cols(1, df_sheet.max_column):
  ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current
  Current += 1

counter=0

for row_cells in df_sheet.iter_rows():
  // add this:
  if counter!=0:
    ws.cell(row=1,column=counter).value = row_cells[0].value

  if row_cells[ColNames['type']].value == 'int':
    for i in range(2,201):
      ws.cell(row=i,column=counter).value = random.randint(-10000,10000)
  if row_cells[ColNames['type']].value == 'char':
    for i in range(2,201):
      ws.cell(row=i,column=counter).value = chr(random.randint(65,90))
  if row_cells[ColNames['type']].value == 'string':
    for i in range(2,201):
      ws.cell(row=i,column=counter).value = fake_data.name()
  counter+=1
wb.save('testdata.xlsx')
```

My input file looks like:

| col_name | type |
| --- | --- |
| name | string |
| address | string |
| city | char |
| phonenum | int |

My output looks like:

| name | address | city | phonenum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| saurabh | adgsdf | C | 4534 |
| eeshan | sgsdfsd | A | 356356 |
| ravinder | adgadf | G | 45343 |